# AWS Private APIGW Implementation without ALB/NLB

Tags: aws-api-gateway, vpc-endpoint

I have a situation where the Private Subnets are running out of IP addresses.

We are using Transit Gatweway and Direct Connect from customer on-premise.

I have created a VPC Endpoint for APIGW. There are needs to access private APIGWs (there will be a few Pvt APIGWs) from on-premise. If I use ALB/NLB, it will consume more IP addresses and we are running out of IP adresses.

Is there anyway to access Private APIGW without and ALB/NLB?

Answer (score 0):

When you associate the VPC endpoint with your private APIGW, APIGW will generate a Route53 Alias Record. So you can access it with a base URL like this:

```
https://{rest-api-id}-{vpce-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}
```